# How to Sort a List of Strings using Velocity script's SortTool?

Tags: java, string, sorting, velocity

I am trying to sort a list of Strings from within Velocity script. This si as simple as calling

```
$sorter.sort($listObjects)
```

but this automatically sorts ascending. In order to sort descending, you must specify a second parameter:

```
$sorter.sort($listObjects, $property)
```

where $property is the property of a bean to access. However, the simple String class is not a Java bean and has no properties (to my knowledge).

How do I sort a list of Strings in descending order through Velocity script?

Comment: don't forget to hit accept if it works...

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
$sorter.sort($objects, ["name:asc", "ordinal:desc"]))
```

from:

https://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/SortTool.html

Answer (score 0):

I think this cannot be done. The SortTool's :asc or :desc feature can only be used when sorting properties, not on simple String values.

You can see why if you look at the source code of the [CollectionTool](https://github.com/apache/velocity-tools/blob/master/velocity-tools-generic/src/main/java/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/CollectionTool.java). The sort of arrays, Collections or Maps internally all add a null parameter as second argument for sorting.